# reinitialize a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

If I've to reinitialize a NSArray with others values, is it right to do this?

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil];
// ...
// some code
// ...
array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj3, obj4, nil];
```

thanks

Comment: use NSMutableArray for this

Comment: @JustSid yep, i'm using ARC

Comment: can you please explain in what situation r u using like this??

Comment: @Alex nothing particular, it was only a doubt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely right. The new object is completely different than the previous. The object pointer now points to a new object and the old one will be released, since you are using ARC.

It is not exactly the same as reinitializing because you throw away the object and getting a new, but NSArray is immutable so this is the only way to "reinitialize" it.

Comment: As a bonus, OP could join the modern world and use `@[obj3, obj4]`

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not re-initialze an `NSArray`. It just assigns a new object to the variable `array`. That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this code may help you. At least, I thing this may be a suitable solution, especially if you are using ARC:

NSObject *obj1 = [NSNull null];
NSObject *obj2 = [NSNull null];

NSMutableArray *arrayObj = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil];

[arrayObj removeAllObjects];

arrayObj = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, nil];

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can reinitialize  NSArray with same name ,you will not get any error or warning but the latest objects gets replaced with previous objects.The previous objects overwrites. For this you have to use ARC otherwise memory problem will occurs.

Comment: can you please explain in what situation r u using like this??